# Golang GORM `has many` or `many2many` association append with condition

Tags: go, associations, go-gorm, has-many

I'm using `gorm` to manage my database, but here is a problem: How to append to an association with condition?

Let me explain more detail:

*example struct(model) code*

```golang
type Group struct {
    ID        int `gorm:"primaryKey; autoIncrement"`
    CreatedAt int
    UpdatedAt int
    Name      string
    Users     []*User 
}

type User struct {
    ID        int `gorm:"primaryKey; autoIncrement"`
    CreatedAt int
    UpdatedAt int
    GroupID   int
    Name      string
    Books     []*Book   
}

type Book struct {
    ID        int `gorm:"primaryKey; autoIncrement"`
    CreatedAt int
    UpdatedAt int
    Name      string
    UserID    int
}
```

The idea here is that `Group` has many `User`, and each `User` can have many `Book`. Now I want to add a `Book` to a `User`, let's say add to `GroupName1 -> UserName1 -> Books`, how to achieve this?

I now using `gorm.Preload("Users.Books")` to preload all the tables, and using `for-loop` to match the correct `Group.Name` and `User.Name`, then get the correct `Group.ID` and `User.ID`, finally manually insert a book that has the right IDs. example code here:

```golang
groups := make([]*Group, 0)
if err := db.Preload("Users.Books").Find(&groups); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

correctGroupName := "group1"
correctUserName := "user1"
newBookName := "newBook"

for _, g := range groups {
    if g.Name == correctGroupName {
        for _, u := range g.Users {
            if u.Name == correctUserName {
                correctUserId := u.ID
                if err := DB.Create(&Book{Name: correctBookName, UserID: correctUserId}); err != nil { 
                    panic(err) 
                }
                break
            }
        break
        }
    }
}
```

But this may be to complex, so is there anyway using `gorm.Association` to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you `select` the right user/group?

Comment: @some-user Yeah that's a way to do it too, but I'm afraid using select, then insert would cost additional operation to the db(But `Preload` may also be an additional operation too), and I would like to use `gorm` to manager those relations(the example is just a tiny part of the data structure) rather than myself, otherwise I could just use the native `sql` library with raw sql command

Comment: @some-user Yeah that's a way to do it too, but I'm afraid using select, then insert would cost additional operation to the db(But `Preload` may also be an additional operation too), and I would like to use `gorm` to manager those relations(the example is just a tiny part of the data structure) rather than myself, otherwise I could just use the native `sql` library with raw sql command

Comment: You could use a subquery to avoid the additional roundtrip. (Either in GORM or raw SQL.)